# API permissions in client app to call Graph search api for microsoft.graph.driveItem

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-search-server

What API permissions does Azure AD client app needs to get token for calling Graph search for microsoft.graph.driveItem ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files

According to the documentation I only need the following permissions:

Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All

But, when i use token returned , it doesnt work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr4D3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Should be below one based on my testing.

[image]

[image]

[official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions)